# IOS 11 Application Crashes When PushKit Receive Push While App is Terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c

Our application started to act weird when ios 11 update is released. We are using pushkit to receive push notifications related with incoming call and messages.
While the app is not in the background(in terminated state), when a push notification arrives IOS raises our app and execute didFinishLaunching method than notification arrives to didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload method
However after updating to IOS 11 we found out that while the app is terminated sometimes we cannot receive notifications and when we checked the crashlogs we saw that app is crashing and as the reason IOS says cpu usage but it succesfully executes didFinishLaunching method(we put logs to the end of the method and they are printed)

We dont know what may cause this problem, does anyone have any idea about the changes in IOS 11 to trigger that problem

Below you can find our crashlog

```
Incident Identifier: 6ED4EB5C-7E9E-4639-860B-312A48C74F49
CrashReporter Key:   cbdfc5f8b24a9e7b992bec953fb095b1909482bc
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,1
Process:             DTimmmr [4534]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B3B6FE24-DBCE-4966-9C6D-18778F73E668/DTimmmr.app/DTimmmr
Identifier:          com.genband.immmrMagenta
Version:             7.3.3.791 (0.94)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.genband.immmrMagenta [3863]


Date/Time:           2017-11-06 21:58:45.0631 +0300
Launch Time:         2017-11-06 21:58:39.6223 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.1 (15B93)
Baseband Version:    3.21.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.genband.immmrMagenta exhausted CPU time allowance of 3.96 seconds |  | Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.920 (user 7.920, system 0.000), 78% CPU | Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.525, 54% CPU | 
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Main Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreUI                          0x00000001891f9938 _CUICopySortedKeySignature + 232
1   CoreUI                          0x00000001891f9894 _CUICopySortedKeySignature + 68
2   CoreUI                          0x00000001891f9c14 CUICopyKeySignatureWithPrefix + 284
3   CoreUI                          0x0000000189241680 -[CUIStructuredThemeStore copyKeySignatureForKey:withBytesNoCopy:length:] + 60
4   CoreUI                          0x000000018922a0b8 -[CUIMutableStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:] + 64
5   CoreUI                          0x000000018922a05c -[CUIMutableStructuredThemeStore canGetRenditionWithKey:] + 20
6   CoreUI                          0x000000018926d3c0 -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:displayGamut:layoutDirection:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:iconSizeIndex:] + 2192
7   CoreUI                          0x000000018926cb2c -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyForName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:displayGamut:layoutDirection:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:withBaseKeySelector:] + 308
8   CoreUI                          0x000000018926896c -[CUICatalog _imageWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:displayGamut:layoutDirection:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 184
9   CoreUI                          0x0000000189268acc -[CUICatalog imageWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:displayGamut:layoutDirection:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 156
10  CoreUI                          0x00000001892687a8 -[CUICatalog imageWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:displayGamut:layoutDirection:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 160
11  UIKit                           0x000000018bec6a88 -[UIImageAsset imageWithTraitCollection:] + 628
12  UIKit                           0x000000018bec7d70 -[_UIPathLazyImageAsset imageWithTraitCollection:] + 400
13  UIKit                           0x000000018b4ad594 +[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] + 380
14  UIKit                           0x000000018b329160 +[UIImage imageNamed:] + 124
15  DTimmmr                         0x000000010465acc8 +[UIStorage loadPixelPreciseImageNamed:] + 3747016 (UIStorage.mm:425)
16  DTimmmr                         0x000000010461b2b8 -[WelcomeScreenViewController viewDidLoad] + 3486392 (WelcomeScreenViewController.mm:47)
17  UIKit                           0x000000018b208f08 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
18  UIKit                           0x000000018b2b05f8 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 76
19  UIKit                           0x000000018b2afa98 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 196
20  UIKit                           0x000000018b2af49c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1168
21  UIKit                           0x000000018b2aef18 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164
22  UIKit                           0x000000018b2aee18 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
23  UIKit                           0x000000018b478f74 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
24  UIKit                           0x000000018b46c318 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 288
25  UIKit                           0x000000018b48418c __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 152
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d7a0fc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d799cc __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 288
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d776dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1068
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
30  GraphicsServices                0x0000000183b2ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100
31  UIKit                           0x000000018b26c2f4 UIApplicationMain + 208
32  DTimmmr                         0x00000001042d8038 main + 65592 (main.m:15)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001817ba56c start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c412c620.events
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8c18 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817574d0 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181757d40 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188326aa8 0x188323000 + 15016
4   CoreLocation                    0x000000018832c53c 0x188323000 + 38204
5   CoreLocation                    0x000000018832c26c 0x188323000 + 37484
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188383f58 0x188323000 + 397144
7   CoreLocation                    0x000000018838032c 0x188323000 + 381740
8   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188380250 0x188323000 + 381520
9   CoreLocation                    0x0000000188381ae4 0x188323000 + 387812
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181a367d0 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181a34168 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 984
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755118 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018176b8b8 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 356
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175ed00 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018176c534 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 952
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175ed00 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175f7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175ed00 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175f7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181760200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817684a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fafd0 _pthread_wqthread + 932
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac20 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  7543851008
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac1c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8a3c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d79c74 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d77840 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001826c16e4 -[NSRunLoop+ 50916 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001826e0afc -[NSRunLoop+ 178940 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018bdcb2f4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001827c2860 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  7619425472  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818e9150 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fed30 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   Foundation                      0x00000001826d3b44 -[NSObject+ 125764 (NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 764
3   Foundation                      0x00000001826d7e28 -[NSObject+ 142888 (NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 144
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104476f64 -[GsmAddressBookManager _initAddressBookObj] + 1765220 (GsmAddressBookManager.mm:163)
5   DTimmmr                         0x000000010447a624 -[GsmAddressBookManager implicitlyLoadAddressBookContacts] + 1779236 (GsmAddressBookManager.mm:892)
6   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a1d924 -[NSObject(DebounceSelector) debounceSelector:object:timeout:] + 7690532 (NSObject+DebounceSelector.m:78)
7   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a1d6b0 -[NSObject(DebounceSelector) debounceSelector:timeout:] + 7689904 (NSObject+DebounceSelector.m:56)
8   DTimmmr                         0x000000010447a594 -[GsmAddressBookManager loadAddressBookContacts] + 1779092 (GsmAddressBookManager.mm:879)
9   DTimmmr                         0x000000010447a264 __53-[GsmAddressBookManager asyncLoadAddressBookContacts]_block_invoke + 1778276 (GsmAddressBookManager.mm:864)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175c090 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 716
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817621c8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 596
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181761f10 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fb120 _pthread_wqthread + 1268
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac20 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  7619384576  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001819f7f0c DYLD-STUB$$OSAtomicAdd32 + 0
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181de214c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar add:object:observer:tokenRegistration:] + 460
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ca3d94 _CFXNotificationRegisterObserver + 1332
3   Foundation                      0x00000001826b8530 -[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:] + 392
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104622010 -[Contact initWithFirstName:andLastName:andDisplayName:] + 3514384 (Contact.mm:116)
5   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104627c94 +[Contact contactWithDictionary:] + 3538068 (Contact.mm:906)
6   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104479f0c -[GsmAddressBookManager _getCachedContactsFromArray:] + 1777420 (GsmAddressBookManager.mm:841)
7   DTimmmr                         0x000000010447a10c __58-[GsmAddressBookManager _asyncGetCachedContactsFromArray:]_block_invoke + 1777932 (GsmAddressBookManager.mm:856)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181762378 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1028
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181761f10 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fb120 _pthread_wqthread + 1268
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac20 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8a3c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d79c74 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d77840 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   AVFAudio                        0x0000000187580774 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry+ 542580 (void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001875ab018 CAPThread::Entry+ 716824 (CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  Thread 0x0x127d240a0
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818e9570 __select + 8
1   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f26148 rtc::PhysicalSocketServer::Wait+ 12968264 (int, bool) + 696
2   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f1706c rtc::MessageQueue::Get+ 12906604 (rtc::Message*, int, bool) + 1064
3   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f2fc1c rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages+ 13007900 (int) + 120
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f2fb84 rtc::Thread::PreRun+ 13007748 (void*) + 104
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  Thread 0x0x127d24240
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818e9150 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fed30 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104ef92e8 rtc::Event::Wait+ 12784360 (int) + 244
3   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f1dae4 rtc::NullSocketServer::Wait+ 12933860 (int, bool) + 16
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f1706c rtc::MessageQueue::Get+ 12906604 (rtc::Message*, int, bool) + 1064
5   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f2fc1c rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages+ 13007900 (int) + 120
6   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f2fb84 rtc::Thread::PreRun+ 13007748 (void*) + 104
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  Thread 0x0x127d243e0
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818e9150 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fed30 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104ef92e8 rtc::Event::Wait+ 12784360 (int) + 244
3   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f1dae4 rtc::NullSocketServer::Wait+ 12933860 (int, bool) + 16
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f1706c rtc::MessageQueue::Get+ 12906604 (rtc::Message*, int, bool) + 1064
5   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f2fce8 rtc::Thread::ProcessMessages+ 13008104 (int) + 324
6   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f2fb84 rtc::Thread::PreRun+ 13007748 (void*) + 104
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  VoiceProcessThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818e9150 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fed30 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104ef92b8 rtc::Event::Wait+ 12784312 (int) + 196
3   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104f089d4 webrtc::EventWrapperImpl::Wait+ 12847572 (unsigned long) + 16
4   DTimmmr                         0x00000001051839d0 webrtc::ProcessThreadImpl::Process+ 15448528 () + 876
5   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104efa06c rtc::PlatformThread::Run+ 12787820 () + 400
6   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104ef9ed0 rtc::PlatformThread::StartThread+ 12787408 (void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  7548104896
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac1c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12 name:  7617291584  Dispatch queue: WebRequestsOperationQueue (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818ea800 kevent_id + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817708f8 _dispatch_kq_poll + 204
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817712c0 _dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership$VARIANT$mp + 432
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181763018 _dispatch_sync_wait + 416
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a84d74 -[DDLog queueLogMessage:asynchronously:] + 8113524 (DDLog.m:370)
5   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a85438 -[DDLog log:message:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:] + 8115256 (DDLog.m:510)
6   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a852d4 +[DDLog log:message:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:] + 8114900 (DDLog.m:0)
7   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a84f1c +[DDLog log:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:format:] + 8113948 (DDLog.m:403)
8   DTimmmr                         0x00000001045de72c +[FSPLogger logAsync:level:flag:context:tag:function:format:] + 3237676 (FSPLogger.m:89)
9   DTimmmr                         0x00000001047f0ebc -[KandySDKLogger logWithLevel:andLogString:] + 5410492 (KandySDKLogger.m:37)
10  DTimmmr                         0x0000000104da4724 -[KandyLoggerMediator logWithDate:andThreadName:andLevel:andFileName:andLine:andMethodName:andLogString:] + 508
11  DTimmmr                         0x0000000104dc9af4 -[KandyBaseWebRequestOperation connection:didReceiveResponse:] + 380
12  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825a9d48 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 60
13  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825a9cec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204
14  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825a9e60 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
15  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182564f60 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveResponse+ 2170720 (_CFURLConnection*, _CFURLResponse*, void const*) + 84
16  CFNetwork                       0x00000001824b402c invocation function for block in URLConnectionClient_Classic::_delegate_didReceiveResponse+ 1445932 (_CFURLResponse*) + 108
17  CFNetwork                       0x00000001824af9d0 invocation function for block in URLConnectionClient_Classic::_withDelegateAsync(char const*, void + 1427920 (_CFURLConnection*, CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMax const*) block_pointer) + 108
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175c6c8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
20  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182581f94 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block+ 2289556 (void const*, void*) + 36
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97900 CFArrayApplyFunction + 80
22  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182581e58 RunloopBlockContext::perform+ 2289240 () + 128
23  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825831d8 MultiplexerSource::perform+ 2294232 () + 312
24  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182582f38 MultiplexerSource::_perform+ 2293560 (void*) + 60
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d7a2e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d7a268 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d79af0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d776c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ce7098 CFRunLoopRun + 116
31  DTimmmr                         0x0000000104dc85c0 -[KandyBaseWebRequestOperation start] + 680
32  Foundation                      0x000000018279f004 __NSOQSchedule_f + 404
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175d3d4 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 428
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175bcd4 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 604
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817621c8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 596
37  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181761f10 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fb120 _pthread_wqthread + 1268
39  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac20 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13 name:  com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8a3c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d79c74 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d77840 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001826c16e4 -[NSRunLoop+ 50916 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   DTimmmr                         0x000000010534bba8 -[_SRRunLoopThread main] + 252
7   Foundation                      0x00000001827c2860 __NSThread__start__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8a3c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d79c74 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d77840 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182402264 +[NSURLConnection+ 717412 (Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6   Foundation                      0x00000001827c2860 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc31c _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fc1e8 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001819fac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 15 name:  7617336192  Dispatch queue: cocoa.lumberjack
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001818c8c00 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001817573d4 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181758328 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 196
3   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a86840 -[DDLog lt_log:] + 8120384 (DDLog.m:844)
4   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a84dd0 __40-[DDLog queueLogMessage:asynchronously:]_block_invoke + 8113616 (DDLog.m:362)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175dae8 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a84d74 -[DDLog queueLogMessage:asynchronously:] + 8113524 (DDLog.m:370)
8   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a85438 -[DDLog log:message:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:] + 8115256 (DDLog.m:510)
9   DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a852d4 +[DDLog log:message:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:] + 8114900 (DDLog.m:0)
10  DTimmmr                         0x0000000104a84f1c +[DDLog log:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:format:] + 8113948 (DDLog.m:403)
11  DTimmmr                         0x00000001045de72c +[FSPLogger logAsync:level:flag:context:tag:function:format:] + 3237676 (FSPLogger.m:89)
12  DTimmmr                         0x00000001047f0ebc -[KandySDKLogger logWithLevel:andLogString:] + 5410492 (KandySDKLogger.m:37)
13  DTimmmr                         0x0000000104da4724 -[KandyLoggerMediator logWithDate:andThreadName:andLevel:andFileName:andLine:andMethodName:andLogString:] + 508
14  DTimmmr                         0x0000000104dc9af4 -[KandyBaseWebRequestOperation connection:didReceiveResponse:] + 380
15  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825a9d48 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 60
16  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825a9cec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204
17  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825a9e60 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
18  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182564f60 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveResponse+ 2170720 (_CFURLConnection*, _CFURLResponse*, void const*) + 84
19  CFNetwork                       0x00000001824b402c invocation function for block in URLConnectionClient_Classic::_delegate_didReceiveResponse+ 1445932 (_CFURLResponse*) + 108
20  CFNetwork                       0x00000001824af9d0 invocation function for block in URLConnectionClient_Classic::_withDelegateAsync(char const*, void + 1427920 (_CFURLConnection*, CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMax const*) block_pointer) + 108
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181755048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018175c6c8 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
23  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182581f94 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block+ 2289556 (void const*, void*) + 36
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181c97900 CFArrayApplyFunction + 80
25  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182581e58 RunloopBlockContext::perform+ 2289240 () + 128
26  CFNetwork                       0x00000001825831d8 MultiplexerSource::perform+ 2294232 () + 312
27  CFNetwork                       0x0000000182582f38 MultiplexerSource::_perform+ 2293560 (void*) + 60
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181d7a2e8
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am seeing something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found out that, in ios11 apple reduces the time that is needed to start the application while the app is in background(In our case it was 2.9 seconds), so when you go beyond it, app is automaticaly killed by IOS.
So we find the solution as minimizing the loading times (such as minimizing the splash screens etc..) and also removing the codes which is not neccesarily need to work on background. And we made our app to launch at 1.8 seconds than crash problem is resolved